# Como retornar o valor de um ID ao selecionar um registro de um auto completar

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompletar

Boa tarde. Reformulando minha dúvida. Como disse estou fazendo um site de vendas em asp.net. Tentei criar um mecanismo de busca, estilo Google e Facebook, que vai filtrando os resultados. Descobri que em asp.net seria muito complicado, então me deram a dica de usar um componente de jquery, o autocomplete. Utilizando esse código abaixo, o autocomplete manda os dados para minha classe handler, e lá vai filtrando e me retornando os possíveis produtos que o usuário está pesquisando. Meu problema é na hora em que o usuário seleciona um dos registro que o autocomplete apresenta. Preciso pegar o ID daquele determinado registro para fazer o redirecionamento para a página correta. O problema é que não consigo pegar esse ID. Gostaria de saber se o erro está na minha classe Handler, ou no jquery. Não sei se tenho que atribuir meu Id a um value para jquery ler, e se tiver não sei em qual parte atribuir.

**Eis o código do HANDLER**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Demo
{
    public class StudentHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            List<string> listProds = new List<string>();

            string cs =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_pesquisar_produtos", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@pesquisa",
                Value = term
            });
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                listProds.Add(rdr["codigo"].ToString());
                listProds.Add(rdr["Descricao"].ToString());
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listProds));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**E o código Asp.Net**

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
     CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"
     Inherits="Demo.WebForm1" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtName').autocomplete({
            source: 'StudentHandler.ashx'
        });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
     <body style="font-family: Arial">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Student Name :
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
      </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Quando executado lhe retorna algum erro?

Comment: Então @Fabricio , erro não me retorna. Faço a pesquisa certinho. Ou seja, vou digitando e o autocomplete vai me retornando os possíveis registros. Mas o que não estou conseguindo fazer, é capturar o Id daquele determinado registro, no momento que o usuário clica no registro desejado.

Comment: Bom eu não manjo de asp.net, mas creio que você possa mesclar seu código com jquery. É possível que esse exemplo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete te dê uma luz.

Comment: *"Descobri que em asp.net seria muito complicado"*. Por que seria muito complicado?

Comment: Teria que usar o evento textChanced, e pelo que vi usar só asp.net seria bem mais difícil fazer algo parecido como o autcomplete.